# Converter Byte para Texto normal c#

Tags: c#

Preciso ler um byte (Buffer), e converter ele para Texto comum, ou seja, preciso converter para letras e/ou números da tabela ASCII.

Estou usando essa função para converter para ASCII
OBS: quando eu coloco:

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
string result2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
string hexaSemespaco = result2.Replace("#", "");
string test = hexaSemespaco.Substring(1, (hexaSemespaco.Length - 2)); //Tem um símbolo que é ocultado
string convert = ConvertHex(test); //aqui dá o erro, parece que há conflito entre tipos de variaveis, mas não enho ctz`insira o código aqui`

public static string ConvertHex(string hexString)
{
    try
    {
        string ascii = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string hs = string.Empty;

            hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
            uint decval = System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
            char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
            ascii += character;

        }

        return ascii;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StreamWriter vWriterr = new StreamWriter(@"c:\POCtest.txt", true);
        vWriterr.WriteLine("ERRO: " + ex.Message);
        vWriterr.Flush();
        vWriterr.Close();
    }
    return "DEU RUIM";
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa, você quer converter `byte[]` para texto ASCII ? ou quer converter para hexadecimal ?

Comment: Quero converter byte para texto ASCII, mas pra isso eu converti para hexa primeiro, para depois converter pra ASCII

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para ASCII:

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray);
```

Para Hexadecimal String (Método 1):

```
string result = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray);
```

Para Hexadecimal String (Método 2):

```
public static string ConvertHex(byte[] byteArray)
{
  return BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("-","");
}
```

Para Hexadecimal String (Método 3):

```
public static string ConvertHex(byte[] byteArray)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

Hexa para String:

```
string HexStringToString(string hexString) 
{
    if (hexString == null || (hexString.Length & 1) == 1) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2) {
        var hexChar = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
        sb.Append((char)Convert.ToByte(hexChar, 16));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Resposta original: [StackOverFlow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/6647038).

Comment: Sim, isso eu tenho ,ele me retorna um Hexadecimal, mas depois que eu tento converter esse hexa para Letras normais dá um problema, e como estou executando como um Windows Service, não mostra erro, simplesmente para o serviço.

Comment: @LeandroKojima coloca na sua pergunta como você está tentando fazer, coloca código que fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: Desculpa por perguntar isso, mas como coloco código aqui? primeira vez que uso o StackOverflow

Comment: @LeandroKojima aqui é comentário, na pergunta mesmo, lá em cima.

Comment: @LeandroKojima clica "editar"